# TextView with rounded corners displays correctly in xml file but not app?

Tags: android

I have a `Textview` on which I am trying to add rounded corners on.

My `TextView`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_answer_one"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />
```

and my `Drawable` file:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="15dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

When I check in the XML Editor (I don't know what it's called) in Android Studio, you can clearly see that the TextView have rounded corners. However, when I run the app on my phone the TextView does not have rounded corners. How come? Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: try setting each corner radius individual

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I tried by setting bottomLeftRadius etc but my textview does not change. This way I don't see rounded corners in the editor either.

Comment: oh, ok, I see. You don't need any layer-list for thius. Just use `shape` as the root element of your XML

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Check my answer Bro

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I tried that too, kinda like MuntasirAonik answer, same problem as before. Shows in editor but not app?

Comment: You may have changed the background in code or the padding of the Text-view was changed in code as this makes the background with its rounded corners, inside the Text-view instead of its borders

Comment: @MuntasirAonik Thanks, but 1) that's exactly what I suggested in the comment. 2) I don't need any answers as I didn't ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Shape :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#CCCCCC"/>
</shape>
```

Example Xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/r"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text View"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         />
    </LinearLayout>
```